# How do you link to a post and highlight a portion of its text?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

[This comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201483/what-happens-to-end-of-turn-saving-throws-to-end-a-condition-after-combat-ends#comment550087_201483) links to an answer to a related question, and when taken to the [linked post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195530/are-rounds-just-for-combat-or-should-we-be-using-them-at-other-times-in-the-gam#:%7E:text=Rounds%20are%20for%20combat%2C%20yes,but%20also%20fast%2Dpaced%20situations.), a portion of the text is highlighted:

[image]

What is this sorcery? How do you do this?

Answer (score 16):

This is a feature specific to the Chrome browser, not this website. You'll see the link from that comment leads to a URL like this: `https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195530/are-rounds-just-for-combat-or-should-we-be-using-them-at-other-times-in-the-gam#:~:text=Rounds%20are%20for%20combat%2C%20yes,but%20also%20fast%2Dpaced%20situations.`

That's long, but toward the end is that `#:~:text=` parameter followed by a bunch of text. This instructs Chrome to highlight this text wherever it's found on the page, and possibly also to scroll to this text. The Google search engine makes heavy use of this feature.

The technical term for this feature is a “text fragment” or a “scroll-to-text fragment”. Other browsers don't implement this feature yet, so don't depend on everyone seeing this highlighting.

Read more about it here:

- [Google blog post about the feature (April 15, 2021)](https://blog.google/products/chrome/more-helpful-chrome-throughout-your-workday/)
- [Text fragments technical spec](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/)
- [Scroll-To-Text fragment browser support](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment)